# rtmfp NetGroup - not all clients see messages inside group

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, p2p, rtmfp

I have Flex application - it connects to FMS and joins to NetGroup named "default".

So I have for example 4 clients connected to the same server in the same group. And looks like not all clients are connected to each other! Client1 sees Client2's streams and messages but doesn't see others. Same for Client3 and 4.

I know UDP must not be blocked in networks in order to P2P connections work, and this can be a reason why not all members of group see each other.

My question is - if there any ways to make all clients see each other? For example - if no P2P  connection can be established - connect client via Flash Media Server or some proxy?

Comment: can you show the code of what you're trying to do?  It's definitely possible, but I'm not sure you're implementing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some very good info about RTMP on RTMFP failover here:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/real-time-collaboration.html
- http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/04/adobes-real-time-media-flow-pr.html